# Android and time

Tags: java, android

I have loop for:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 2000; i++)
```

How I can change this  loop that instead of int < 2000 I can get time:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 2000(miliseconds); i++)
```

I want to do this loop until time is less then 2000 miliseconds.I mean that this loop must working for 2 seconds and after 2 sec break.

In loop I doing some operations. I save position of cursor. I want save that position for 2 seconds.

Comment: Does the loop do anything or are just requiring a pause for 2 seconds?

Comment: so you want users of your app to have their battery power used to run empty loops ?

Comment: @SirDarius: you're assuming he doesn't do anything in the body of the for-loop, which isn't shown in his snippets...

Comment: @maerics yeah, the formatting of the question tends towards an interpretation such as mine, I recommend the poster to use placeholders to make things clearer such as: `for (int i = 1; i < 2000; i++) { /* some code... */ }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to do something in a loop until 2000ms has passed:

```
long then = new Date().getTime() + 2000/*ms*/;
do {
  // Do some work here...
  long now = new Date().getTime();
} while (now < then);
```

**[Edit]** As commenter @CheJami points out, there's no need to create a Date object since you can get the current time in milliseconds directly:

```
long then = System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000/*ms*/;
do {
  // Do some work here...
  long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
} while (now < then);
```

This strategy will likely result in better performance overall since there is no need to repeatedly create new objects and eventually garbage collect them.

Comment: I'm not suggesting he busy-waits, I'm suggesting he does some work, per the "Do some work here" comment...

Comment: Why do you need to create a `Date` object just to work out elapsed time? This will just create more allocations for the GC to feed off.

Answer (score 3):

Without having to create a `Date` object constantly, here is an alternative answer:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 2000){
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just an empty loop, to delay execution of subsequent code, then you need to restructure things a bit. You will need to put the delayed code in a `Runnable`, and use [`Handler.postDelayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) to call it after a certain time. You can't just sit there in a loop waiting.

Comment: unless he actually does something in the loop?